# JavaScript: from this code how to change the order of the divs and remove inline style

Tags: javascript, html

I am using a Joomla extension that display a slide show Ken Burns style. The slide show can be seen here: http://samples.websonalized.com/waterdamage

This extension uses java script to achieve the Ken Burns effect; I do not know Java

I would like to move the Description div (which contains the image's title and the image's description) to the left of the slideshow;

When the code is rendered, the slideshow div has the following structure:

```
<div id="slidewrap> ...
   <div id="slideshow"> ...
      <div id="captionDiv"> ...
      </div>
   <div>
<div>
```

This inline styling and rendering of the divs is generated through two Java Files, not through a .php nor .html file. Meaning, there is no file with

```
<div id="slidewrap> execute java
   <div id="slideshow"> execute java
      <div id="captionDiv"> execute java
      </div>
   <div>
<div>
```

but rather, a template file (or view file) .php with a simple:

```
echo "<div id="slidewrap"></div>";
```

And as I look at the Java files I do not understand a thing. Each of these divs has the styling inline, and therefore is difficult to manipulate through a CSS external file

I would like to change the hierarchy of the divs to the following order:

```
<div id="slidewrap> ...
   <div id="slideshow"> ...
   <div>
   <div id="captionDiv"> ...
   </div>
<div>
```

From the Java Code files, what would I modify to change the divs hierarchy

AND, what would I change to erase the inline styling of captionDiv?

It is a loaded question. So, thank you in advance

The helper.php file:

```
class slideshowHelper
{

    function loadScripts($params, $imagePath, $images) {
        $doc = &JFactory::getDocument();
        JHTML::_('behavior.mootools');
        $doc->addScript('modules/mod_rokslideshow/tmpl/rokslideshow'.modRokSlideshowHelper::_getJSVersion().'.js');

        $showCaption    = $params->get( 'showCaption', 1 );
        $showTitleCaption   = $params->get( 'showTitleCaption', 1 );
        $externals = $params->get('externals', 0);
        $heightCaption = $params->get('heightCaption', 45);
        $width = $params->get( 'width', 400 );
        $height = $params->get( 'height', 300 );
        $altTag = $params->get( 'altTag', 'RokSlideshow - http://www.rocketwerx.com' );
        $imageDuration = $params->get( 'imageDuration', 9000 );
        $transDuration = $params->get( 'transDuration', 2000);
        $transType = $params->get( 'transType', 'combo');
        $transition = $params->get( 'transition', 'Expo.easeOut');
        $pan = $params->get( 'pan', 50);
        $zoom = $params->get( 'zoom', 50);
        $loadingDiv = $params->get( 'loadingDiv', 1);
        $imageResize = $params->get( 'imageResize', 1);
        $titleSize = $params->get( 'titleSize', '13px');
        $titleColor = $params->get( 'titleColor', '#fff');
        $descSize = $params->get( 'descSize', '11px');
        $descColor = $params->get( 'descColor', '#ccc');

        $imgPush = "window.addEvent('load', function() {\n";
        $imgPush .= "   var imgs = [];\n";

        foreach($images as $img) {
            $info = modRokSlideshowHelper::getInfo($imagePath, $img);
            $imgPush .= "   imgs.push({file: '$img', ";
            if ($showCaption == 1) {
                $imgPush .= "title: '".trim($info[0])."', desc: '".trim($info[2])."', url: '".trim($info[1])."'";
            } else {
                $imgPush .= "title: '', desc: '', url: ''";
            }
            $imgPush .= "});\n";
        }

        $imgPush .= "   var myshow = new Slideshow('slideshow', { 
        type: '$transType',
        externals: $externals,
        showTitleCaption: $showTitleCaption,
        captionHeight: $heightCaption,
        width: $width, 
        height: $height, 
        pan: $pan,
        zoom: $zoom,
        loadingDiv: $loadingDiv,
        resize: ". (($imageResize == 1) ? 'true' : 'false').",
        duration: [$transDuration, $imageDuration],
        transition: Fx.Transitions.$transition,
        images: imgs, 
        path: '".JURI::base().$imagePath."'
    });

    myshow.caps.h2.setStyles({color: '$titleColor', fontSize: '$titleSize'});
    myshow.caps.p.setStyles({color: '$descColor', fontSize: '$descSize'});

});";

        $doc->addScriptDeclaration($imgPush);
    }

    //helper functions
    function imageList ($directory, $sortcriteria, $sortorder) {...etc ect
```

THEN FROM THE VIEW FILES

```
JAVA FILE 1 COULD BE THE ONE USED DEPENDING ON THE VERSION FOUND:


eval(function(p,a,c,k,e,r){e=function(c){return(c<a?'':e(parseInt(c/a)))+((c=c%a)>35?String.fromCharCode(c+29):c.toString(36))};if(!''.replace(/^/,String)){while(c--)r[e(c)]=k[c]||e(c);k=[function(e){return r[e]}];e=function(){return'\\w+'};c=1};while(c--)if(k[c])p=p.replace(new RegExp('\\b'+e(c)+'\\b','g'),k[c]);return p}('8 3Z=l 28({2M:[2K,2J],2I:\'4.1 (3R 1.2)\',6:{1m:L,2E:1H,2D:L,1t:[\'3I\',\'3H\',\'3G\'],k:[3E,3D],19:\'/\',M:1H,R:V,1r:L,3y:[/\\./,\'t.\'],1h:1j.3v.3u.3t,18:\'2B\',X:3p,H:L,1s:L},w:{y:{B:{J:0,15:\'1B\',9:\'V%\',1o:0,v:0,1I:0,h:40,2m:\'#1U\',1T:\'#38\',37:0},1b:{1T:\'35\',1P:0,2f:\'32%\',1o:0,1o:\'2d 27\',2Z:\'2Y\'},p:{1P:0,2f:\'2W%\',1o:\'2d 27\',1T:\'#2V\'}}},2s:f(a,b){3.2Q($2P({29:3.29.1i(3)},b));g(!3.6.u)Y;3.6.R=3.22(3.6.R);3.6.X=3.22(3.6.X);3.T=16.1f(a).1p();3.y={B:l E(\'B\',{w:3.w.y.B,\'1W\':\'2S\'}),1b:l E(\'1b\',{w:3.w.y.1b,\'1W\':\'2R\'}),p:l E(\'p\',{w:3.w.y.p,\'1W\':\'2T\'})};3.S=[];8 c=l 2x(3.T,3.6.u,{H:3.6.H,2w:3.1a.1i(3),19:3.6.19,1s:3.6.1s})},1a:f(){3.F=$A(2U);3.a=3.F[0].W().s({w:{1l:\'1n\',15:\'1B\',v:0,\'Z\':0,1G:1}}).17(3.T);8 c=3.a.2X();3.h=3.6.h||c.h;3.9=3.6.9||c.9;3.T.1c({1l:\'1n\',15:\'2j\',9:3.9});3.T.1p();3.T.r((l E(\'B\',{w:{1l:\'1n\',1N:\'1C\',15:\'2j\',9:3.9,h:3.h}})).r(3.a));3.1r(3.a,c);3.b=3.a.W().C(\'J\',0).17(3.a,\'2e\');8 d=3.6.u[0].12;8 e=3.6.u[1].12;8 a=l E(\'a\',{1L:3.6.u[0].12,\'w\':{\'15\':\'1B\',\'Z\':0,\'v\':0,\'J\':1,\'z-I\':1,\'9\':3.9,\'h\':3.h,\'1l\':\'1n\'}}).17(3.a,\'30\').r(3.a);8 b=l E(\'a\',{1L:3.6.u[0].12,\'w\':{\'15\':\'1B\',\'Z\':0,\'v\':0,\'J\':1,\'z-I\':2,\'9\':3.9,\'h\':3.h,\'1l\':\'1n\'}}).17(a,\'2e\').r(3.b);a.C(\'26\',(d!=\'#\'&&d!=\'\')?\'25\':\'24\');b.C(\'26\',(e!=\'#\'&&e!=\'\')?\'25\':\'24\');g(3.6.2E){a.s(\'2A\',\'2c\');b.s(\'2A\',\'2c\')};3.D=[0,0];3.M();3.G=\'v\';3.m=[0,0];16.1f(16.31).r(l E(\'B\',{1f:\'1X\',w:{33:\'1C\',h:0,9:0,1N:\'1C\',J:0}}));3.q=3.F[0];16.1f(\'1X\').r(3.q);3.11()},11:f(a){g($Q()>3.D[0]){3.o=(3.m[1]%2)?3.b:3.a;3.o.1c({J:0,9:\'K\',h:\'K\',1G:3.m[1]});3.o.2g().C(\'z-I\',3.m[1]);8 b=3.6.u[3.m[0]].12;3.o.C(\'26\',(b!=\'#\'&&b!=\'\')?\'25\':\'24\');g(b!=\'#\'&&b!=\'\'){3.o.2g().s(\'1L\',b)}3.o.34({1O:3.q.1O,1d:3.q.1d,1q:3.q.1q});3.1r(3.o,3.q);g(a){3.o.1c({Z:0,v:0,J:1});3.1m();3.1M();Y}3.1m();3[3.6.18.O(/1e|2a/)?\'2h\':\'2i\']();3.1M()}2k{3.1E=3.11.1D(V,3)}},1M:f(){g(3.U){3.U.36(\'a[2l]\').1w(f(a,i){a[(i===3.m[0]?\'39\':\'3a\')+\'28\'](3.6.1t[2])},3)}3.G=\'v\';3.m[0]=(3.m[0]+1)%3.F.13;3.m[1]++;3.D[0]=$Q()+3.6.k[1]+(3.6.18.O(/2B|1e|2a/)?3.6.k[0]:0);3.D[1]=$Q()+3.6.k[0];3.q=3.F[3.m[0]];16.1f(\'1X\').1p().r(3.q);3.11()},2i:f(){3.o.1c({1I:\'K\',14:\'K\',v:\'K\',Z:\'K\'});8 a=[\'v Z\',\'14 Z\',\'v 1I\',\'14 1I\'].3b().3c(\' \');a.1w(f(p){3.o.C(p,0)},3);8 b=3.6.18.O(/X|2n/)?3.X():{};8 c=3.6.18.O(/R|2n/)?3.R(a):{};3.S.1e(l 1j.2o(3.o,{k:3.6.k[0]}).1a(\'J\',1));3.S.1e(l 1j.3d(3.o,{k:3.6.k[0]+3.6.k[1]}).1a($2P(b,c)))},X:f(){8 n=P.2p(3.9/3.q.9,3.h/3.q.h);8 z=(3.6.X===\'20\')?P.2q()+1:(3.6.X.N()/V.0)+1;8 a=P.1J(3.q.h*n);8 b=P.1J(3.q.9*n);8 c=(a*z).N();8 d=(b*z).N();Y{h:[c,a],9:[d,b]}},R:f(a){8 b=3.9-3.o.9,23=3.h-3.o.h;8 p=3.6.R===\'20\'?P.2q():P.3e((3.6.R.N()/V)-1);8 c=(b*p).N(),2r=(23*p).N();8 x=3.9/3.q.9>3.h/3.q.h;8 d={};d[a[x?1:0]]=x?[2r,23]:[c,b];Y d},2h:f(){8 a,1Y={},1K={},x;3.o.1c({v:\'K\',14:\'K\',J:1}).C(3.G,3.9);g(3.6.18===\'2a\'){3.S.1e(l 1j.2o(3.o,{k:3.6.k[0],1h:3.6.1h}).1a(3.G,0))}2k{a=[3.o,3.m[1]%2?3.a:3.b];1Y[3.G]=[3.9,0];1K[3.G]=[0,-3.9];g(a[1].21(3.G)===\'K\'){x=3.9-a[1].21(\'9\').N();a[1].C(3.G,x);a[1].C(3.G===\'v\'?\'14\':\'v\',\'K\');1K[3.G][0]=x}3.S.1e(l 1j.3f(a,{k:3.6.k[0],1h:3.6.1h}).1a({\'0\':1Y,\'1\':1K}))}},1m:f(c){c=c||3.o;g(!3.6.1m||(!c.1d&&!c.1q))Y;3.T.1Z().r(3.y.B.r(3.y.1b,3.y.p));(f(){g(3.6.2D)3.y.1b.s(\'1g\',c.1d);3.y.p.s(\'1g\',c.1q);3.y.B.C(\'1G\',c.21(\'1G\')*2||10);3.1V=3.1V||3.6.3g||3.y.B.3h;8 a=3.y.B.1v({J:0.7,h:[0,3.1V]});8 b=3.y.B;(f(){b.1v({J:0,h:0})}).1D(1.3i*(3.6.k[1]-3.6.k[0]))}).1D(0.3j*(3.6.k[0]),3)},M:f(){g(!3.6.M)Y;8 i,j,1z;8 b=3.6.M.O(/3k/);3.U=l E(\'U\');8 c=l E(\'3l\'),a=l E(\'a\');g(3.6.M.O(/1S/)){3.U.r(c.W().r(a.W().2t(3.6.1t[0]).2u(\'2v\',f(){g(b||$Q()>3.D[1]){$1u(3.1E);g(b){3.S.1w(f(a){a.Q=0;a.s(\'1Q\',{k:0});a.s(\'1v\',{k:0});a.1F(L)})}3.G=\'14\';3.m[0]=(3.m[0]<2)?3.F.13-(2-3.m[0]):3.m[0]-2;3.D=[0];3.q=3.F[3.m[0]];3.11(b)}}.1i(3))))}g(3.6.M.O(/1S\\+|2y/)){2z(i=0,j=3.F.13;i<j;i++){1z=a.W().s(\'2l\',i);g(3.6.M.O(/2y/))1z.C(\'2m-2b\',\'12(\'+3.F[i].1O+\')\');g(i===0)a.3m=3.6.1t[2];1z.3n=f(i){g(b||$Q()>3.D[1]){$1u(3.1E);g(b){3.S.1w(f(a){a.Q=0;a.6.k=0;a.s(\'1Q\',{k:0});a.s(\'1v\',{k:0});a.1F(L)})}3.G=(i<3.m[0]||3.m[0]===0)?\'14\':\'v\';3.m[0]=i;3.D=[0];3.q=3.F[3.m[0]];3.11(b)}}.3o(i,3);3.U.r(c.W().r(1z))}}g(3.6.M.O(/1S/)){3.U.r(c.W().r(a.W().2t(3.6.1t[1]).2u(\'2v\',f(){g(b||$Q()>3.D[1]){$1u(3.1E);g(b){3.S.1w(f(a){a.Q=0;a.s(\'1Q\',{k:0});a.s(\'1v\',{k:0});a.1F(L)})}3.D=[0];3.11(b)}}.1i(3))))}3.U.3q(3.T)},29:f(e){e=l 3r(e).3s();8 a=3.m[1]%3.F.13;8 b=3.m[1]==0?1:a==0?3.F.13:a;8 c=3.6.u[b-1].12;g(c==\'#\'||c==\'\')Y;3w.3x.1L=c},22:f(a,b,c,d){g(a!=\'20\'){a=a.N();a=3z(a)||a<c||a>d?b:a}Y a},1r:f(a,b){8 n;g(3.6.1r){n=P.2p(3.9/b.9,3.h/b.h);a.1c({h:P.1J(b.h*n),9:P.1J(b.9*n)})}}});8 2x=l 28({2M:[2K,2J],2I:\'.5-3A-3B (3C.2)\',6:{H:1H,1R:\'3F u: \',2C:\'\',19:\'\',1s:L},2s:f(a,b,c){3.2Q(c);3.H=(3.6.H)?16.1f(a):1H;3.u=[];3.I=0;3.1x=b.13;g(3.H){3.1y=l E(\'B\').17(3.H);3.1A=l E(\'B\',{w:{9:V,1P:1,1o:\'27 K\',3J:\'v\',1N:\'1C\',3K:\'3L 3M #1U\'}}).r(l E(\'B\',{w:{9:\'0%\',h:10,3N:\'#1U\'}})).17(3.H)}3.2F.1D(3O,3,[b])},2G:f(){3.I=0;g(3.H){3.1A.1Z().C(\'9\',\'0%\');3.1y.s(\'1g\',3.6.1R)}},2F:f(a){8 b=3;3.2G();3.u=[];3.1k=a;3.D=3P(3.2H.1i(3),V);2z(8 i=0,j=a.13;i<j;i++){3.u[i]=l 3Q.2b((3.1k[i].19||3.6.19)+3.1k[i].3S,{1d:b.1k[i].1d,1q:b.1k[i].3T,\'3U\':f(){b.I++},\'3V\':f(){b.I++;b.u.2L(i,1)},\'3W\':f(){b.I++;b.u.2L(i,1)}})}},2H:f(){g(3.H){3.1y.s(\'1g\',3.6.1R+3.I+\'/\'+3.1x+3.6.2C);3.1A.1Z().C(\'9\',(!3.1x?0:3.I.N()*V/3.1x)+\'%\')}g(3.I>=3.1x){3.2N()}},2N:f(){$1u(3.D);g(3.H){3.1y.s(\'1g\',\'3X 3Y\');g(3.6.1s){3.1y.1p().2O();3.1A.1p().2O()}}3.41(\'2w\',3.u)},1F:f(){$1u(3.D)}});',62,250,'|||this|||options||var|width||||||function|if|height|||duration|new|curr||img||loader|adopt|set||images|left|styles||caps|||div|setStyle|timer|Element|imgs|direction|loadingDiv|index|opacity|auto|true|navigation|toInt|test|Math|time|pan|fx|el|ul|100|clone|zoom|return|top||load|url|length|right|position|document|inject|type|path|start|h2|setStyles|title|push|id|html|transition|bind|Fx|sources|display|captions|block|margin|empty|alt|resize|removeDiv|classes|clear|morph|each|total|loadingText|atemp|progressBar|absolute|hidden|delay|timeout|cancel|zIndex|false|bottom|ceil|p1|href|loaded|overflow|src|padding|tween|loadingPrefix|arrows|color|333|capsHeight|class|hiddenDIV|p0|getFirst|rand|getStyle|mask|ey|default|pointer|cursor|5px|Class|onClick|wipe|image|_blank|2px|after|fontSize|getParent|swipe|kens|relative|else|name|background|combo|Tween|max|random|sy|initialize|addClass|addEvent|click|onComplete|ImageLoader|thumbnails|for|target|fade|loadingSuffix|showTitleCaption|externals|loadImages|reset|loadProgress|version|Events|Options|splice|Implements|loadComplete|dispose|merge|setOptions|captionTitle|captionDiv|captionDescription|arguments|eee|60|getCoordinates|bold|fontWeight|before|body|80|visibility|setProperties|red|getElements|textIndent|fff|add|remove|getRandom|split|Morph|abs|Elements|captionHeight|offsetHeight|00|75|fast|li|className|onclick|pass|50|injectInside|Event|stop|easeInOut|Sine|Transitions|window|location|thumbnailre|isNaN|olmo|ver|moo1|4000|2000|loading|active|next|prev|textAlign|border|solid|1px|backgroundColor|200|setInterval|Asset|moo|file|desc|onload|onerror|onabort|Loading|Complete|Slideshow||fireEvent'.split('|'),0,{}))


JAVE FILE 2 COULD BE THE ONE USED DEPENDING ON THE VERSION FOUND:



eval(function(p,a,c,k,e,d){e=function(c){return(c<a?'':e(parseInt(c/a)))+((c=c%a)>35?String.fromCharCode(c+29):c.toString(36))};if(!''.replace(/^/,String)){while(c--){d[e(c)]=k[c]||e(c)}k=[function(e){return d[e]}];e=function(){return'\\w+'};c=1};while(c--){if(k[c]){p=p.replace(new RegExp('\\b'+e(c)+'\\b','g'),k[c])}}return p}('9 2B=k 2h({2F:\'4.1\',6:{1l:R,2M:1L,2Q:R,1q:[\'3h\',\'3u\',\'3t\'],m:[3C,3y],1c:\'/\',V:1L,P:Y,1p:R,3l:[/\\./,\'t.\'],1n:2x.3f.3j.3a,1d:\'2G\',Q:37,I:R,1y:R},v:{E:{B:{K:0,1b:\'1M\',8:\'Y%\',1o:0,s:0,1A:0,f:40,2W:\'#2g\',21:\'#38\',39:0},1e:{21:\'3E\',2e:0,2R:\'3x%\',1o:0,1o:\'2Y 2f\',3w:\'3k\'},p:{2e:0,2R:\'3D%\',1o:\'2Y 2f\',21:\'#3B\'}}},2r:c(N,6){3.2y($2H({27:3.27.1x(3)},6));d(!3.6.u)13;3.6.P=3.2d(3.6.P);3.6.Q=3.2d(3.6.Q);3.N=$(N).1w();3.E={B:k F(\'B\',{v:3.v.E.B,\'22\':\'3v\'}),1e:k F(\'1e\',{v:3.v.E.1e,\'22\':\'3n\'}),p:k F(\'p\',{v:3.v.E.p,\'22\':\'3z\'})};3.l=[];9 3r=k 20(3.N,3.6.u,{I:3.6.I,2K:3.11.1x(3),1c:3.6.1c,1y:3.6.1y})},11:c(){3.J=$A(3s);3.a=3.J[0].14().1E({v:{1i:\'1h\',1b:\'1M\',s:0,\'18\':0,1B:1}}).1z(3.N);9 T=3.a.3q();3.f=3.6.f||T.f;3.8=3.6.8||T.8;3.N.19({1i:\'1h\',1b:\'2t\',8:3.8});3.N.1w();3.N.q((k F(\'B\',{v:{1i:\'1h\',1O:\'1H\',1b:\'2t\',8:3.8,f:3.f}})).q(3.a));3.1p(3.a,T);3.b=3.a.14().D(\'K\',0).3p(3.a);9 1Z=3.6.u[0].o;9 1W=3.6.u[1].o;9 a=k F(\'a\',{1I:3.6.u[0].o,\'v\':{\'1b\':\'1M\',\'18\':0,\'s\':0,\'K\':1,\'z-w\':1,\'8\':3.8,\'f\':3.f,\'1i\':\'1h\'}}).2m(3.a,\'3m\').q(3.a);9 b=k F(\'a\',{1I:3.6.u[0].o,\'v\':{\'1b\':\'1M\',\'18\':0,\'s\':0,\'K\':1,\'z-w\':2,\'8\':3.8,\'f\':3.f,\'1i\':\'1h\'}}).2m(a,\'3A\').q(3.b);a.D(\'1X\',(1Z!=\'#\'&&1Z!=\'\')?\'1Y\':\'23\');b.D(\'1X\',(1W!=\'#\'&&1W!=\'\')?\'1Y\':\'23\');d(3.6.2M){a.1J(\'2N\',\'2I\');b.1J(\'2N\',\'2I\')};3.C=[0,0];3.V();3.H=\'s\';3.h=[0,0];$(3b.3i).q(k F(\'B\',{3g:\'29\',v:{3c:\'1H\',f:0,8:0,1O:\'1H\',K:0}}));3.r=3.J[0];$(\'29\').q(3.r);3.15()},15:c(y){d($U()>3.C[0]){3.g=(3.h[1]%2)?3.b:3.a;3.g.19({K:0,8:\'L\',f:\'L\',1B:3.h[1]});3.g.2u().D(\'z-w\',3.h[1]);9 o=3.6.u[3.h[0]].o;3.g.D(\'1X\',(o!=\'#\'&&o!=\'\')?\'1Y\':\'23\');d(o!=\'#\'&&o!=\'\'){3.g.2u().1J(\'1I\',o)}3.g.4e({1R:3.r.1R,1f:3.r.1f,1s:3.r.1s});3.1p(3.g,3.r);d(y){3.g.19({18:0,s:0,K:1});3.1l();3.24();13}3.1l();3[3.6.1d.X(/1a|26/)?\'2o\':\'2D\']();3.24()}2l{3.1N=3.15.1D(Y,3)}},24:c(){d(3.12){3.12.47(\'a[2V]\').1k(c(a,i){a[(i===3.h[0]?\'45\':\'2b\')+\'2h\'](3.6.1q[2])},3)}3.H=\'s\';3.h[0]=(3.h[0]+1)%3.J.17;3.h[1]++;3.C[0]=$U()+3.6.m[1]+(3.6.1d.X(/2G|1a|26/)?3.6.m[0]:0);3.C[1]=$U()+3.6.m[0];3.r=3.J[3.h[0]];$(\'29\').1w().q(3.r);3.15()},2D:c(){3.g.19({1A:\'L\',16:\'L\',s:\'L\',18:\'L\'});9 G=[\'s 18\',\'16 18\',\'s 1A\',\'16 1A\'].44().43(\' \');G.1k(c(p){3.g.D(p,0)},3);9 Q=3.6.1d.X(/Q|2C/)?3.Q():{};9 P=3.6.1d.X(/P|2C/)?3.P(G):{};3.l.1a(3.g.2k(\'K\',{m:3.6.m[0]}).11(1));3.l.1a(3.g.2P({m:3.6.m[0]+3.6.m[1]}).11($2H(Q,P)))},Q:c(){9 n=S.2q(3.8/3.r.8,3.f/3.r.f);9 z=(3.6.Q===\'2j\')?S.2J()+1:(3.6.Q.W()/Y.0)+1;9 2a=S.1C(3.r.f*n);9 28=S.1C(3.r.8*n);9 2O=(2a*z).W();9 2L=(28*z).W();13{f:[2O,2a],8:[2L,28]}},P:c(G){9 25=3.8-3.g.8,1V=3.f-3.g.f;9 p=3.6.P===\'2j\'?S.2J():S.4b((3.6.P.W()/Y)-1);9 2p=(25*p).W(),2A=(1V*p).W();9 x=3.8/3.r.8>3.f/3.r.f;9 T={};T[G[x?1:0]]=x?[2A,1V]:[2p,25];13 T},2o:c(){9 G,2c={},1G={},x;3.g.19({s:\'L\',16:\'L\',K:1}).D(3.H,3.8);d(3.6.1d===\'26\'){3.l.1a(3.g.2k(3.H,{m:3.6.m[0],1n:3.6.1n}).11(0))}2l{G=[3.g,3.h[1]%2?3.a:3.b];2c[3.H]=[3.8,0];1G[3.H]=[0,-3.8];d(G[1].1T(3.H)===\'L\'){x=3.8-G[1].1T(\'8\').W();G[1].D(3.H,x);G[1].D(3.H===\'s\'?\'16\':\'s\',\'L\');1G[3.H][0]=x}3.l.1a(k 2x.4a(G,{m:3.6.m[0],1n:3.6.1n}).11({\'0\':2c,\'1\':1G}))}},1l:c(g){g=g||3.g;d(!3.6.1l||(!g.1f&&!g.1s))13;3.N.1S().q(3.E.B.q(3.E.1e,3.E.p));(c(){d(3.6.2Q)3.E.1e.1t(g.1f);3.E.p.1t(g.1s);3.E.B.D(\'1B\',g.1T(\'1B\')*2||10);3.1Q=3.1Q||3.6.3N||3.E.B.3J;9 l=3.E.B.2P().1E({\'f\':0}).11({K:0.7,f:3.1Q});(c(){l.11({K:0,f:0})}).1D(1.3O*(3.6.m[1]-3.6.m[0]))}).1D(0.3P*(3.6.m[0]),3)},V:c(){d(!3.6.V)13;9 i,j,1g;9 y=3.6.V.X(/y/);3.12=k F(\'12\');9 1j=k F(\'1j\'),a=k F(\'a\');d(3.6.V.X(/1U/)){3.12.q(1j.14().q(a.14().2U(3.6.1q[0]).2Z(\'30\',c(){d(y||$U()>3.C[1]){$1v(3.1N);d(y){3.l.1k(c(l){l.U=0;l.6.m=0;l.1K(R)})}3.H=\'16\';3.h[0]=(3.h[0]<2)?3.J.17-(2-3.h[0]):3.h[0]-2;3.C=[0];3.r=3.J[3.h[0]];3.15(y)}}.1x(3))))}d(3.6.V.X(/1U\\+|2X/)){33(i=0,j=3.J.17;i<j;i++){1g=a.14().1J(\'2V\',i);d(3.6.V.X(/2X/))1g.D(\'2W-2E\',\'o(\'+3.J[i].1R+\')\');d(i===0)a.3U=3.6.1q[2];1g.3T=c(i){d(y||$U()>3.C[1]){$1v(3.1N);d(y){3.l.1k(c(l){l.U=0;l.6.m=0;l.1K(R)})}3.H=(i<3.h[0]||3.h[0]===0)?\'16\':\'s\';3.h[0]=i;3.C=[0];3.r=3.J[3.h[0]];3.15(y)}}.3R(i,3);3.12.q(1j.14().q(1g))}}d(3.6.V.X(/1U/)){3.12.q(1j.14().q(a.14().2U(3.6.1q[1]).2Z(\'30\',c(){d(y||$U()>3.C[1]){$1v(3.1N);d(y){3.l.1k(c(l){l.U=0;l.6.m=0;l.1K(R)})}3.C=[0];3.15(y)}}.1x(3))))}3.12.1z(3.N)},27:c(e){e=k 48(e).1K();9 2i=3.h[1]%3.J.17;9 w=3.h[1]==0?1:2i==0?3.J.17:2i;9 o=3.6.u[w-1].o;d(o==\'#\'||o==\'\')13;3W.3V.1I=o},2d:c(O,1E,2v,2w){d(O!=\'2j\'){O=O.W();O=3X(O)||O<2v||O>2w?1E:O}13 O},1p:c(T,1m){9 n;d(3.6.1p){n=S.2q(3.8/1m.8,3.f/1m.f);T.19({f:S.1C(1m.f*n),8:S.1C(1m.8*n)})}}});2B.2s(k 2T);9 20=k 2h({2F:\'.5-3e-3d\',6:{I:1L,1P:\'36 u: \',34:\'\',1c:\'\',1y:R},2r:c(31,M,6){3.2y(6);3.I=(3.6.I)?$(31):1L;3.u=[];3.w=0;3.1r=M.17;d(3.I){3.1u=k F(\'B\').1z(3.I);3.1F=k F(\'B\',{v:{8:Y,2e:1,1o:\'2f L\',3Q:\'s\',1O:\'1H\',46:\'3L 3I #2g\'}}).q(k F(\'B\',{v:{8:\'0%\',f:10,41:\'#2g\'}})).1z(3.I)}3.2z.1D(3F,3,[M])},2n:c(){3.w=0;d(3.I){3.1F.1S().D(\'8\',\'0%\');3.1u.1t(3.6.1P)}},2z:c(M){9 Z=3;3.2n();3.u=[];3.M=M;3.C=49(3.35.1x(3),Y);33(9 i=0,j=M.17;i<j;i++){3.u[i]=k 3S.2E((3.M[i].1c||3.6.1c)+3.M[i].42,{1f:Z.M[i].1f,1s:Z.M[i].4c,\'3Y\':c(){Z.w++},\'3K\':c(){Z.w++;Z.u.32(i,1)},\'3H\':c(){Z.w++;Z.u.32(i,1)}})}},35:c(){d(3.I){3.1u.1t(3.6.1P+3.w+\'/\'+3.1r+3.6.34);3.1F.1S().D(\'8\',(!3.1r?0:3.w.W()*Y/3.1r)+\'%\')}d(3.w>=3.1r){3.2S()}},2S:c(){$1v(3.C);d(3.I){3.1u.1t(\'3G 3M\');d(3.6.1y){3.1u.1w().2b();3.1F.1w().2b()}}3.4d(\'2K\',3.u)},3Z:c(){$1v(3.C)}});20.2s(k 3o,k 2T);',62,263,'|||this|||options||width|var|||function|if||height|img|curr|||new|fx|duration||url||adopt|loader|left||images|styles|index||fast|||div|timer|setStyle|caps|Element|arr|direction|loadingDiv|imgs|opacity|auto|sources|el|val|pan|zoom|true|Math|obj|time|navigation|toInt|test|100|self||start|ul|return|clone|load|right|length|top|setStyles|push|position|path|type|h2|title|atemp|block|display|li|each|captions|to|transition|margin|resize|classes|total|alt|setHTML|loadingText|clear|empty|bind|removeDiv|injectInside|bottom|zIndex|ceil|delay|set|progressBar|p1|hidden|href|setProperty|stop|false|absolute|timeout|overflow|loadingPrefix|capsHeight|src|getFirst|getStyle|arrows|ey|url2|cursor|pointer|url1|ImageLoader|color|class|default|loaded|ex|wipe|onClick|ew|hiddenDIV|eh|remove|p0|mask|padding|5px|333|Class|cur|rand|effect|else|inject|reset|swipe|sx|max|initialize|implement|relative|getParent|lower|higher|Fx|setOptions|loadImages|sy|Slideshow|combo|kens|image|version|fade|merge|_blank|random|onComplete|sw|externals|target|sh|effects|showTitleCaption|fontSize|loadComplete|Options|addClass|name|background|thumbnails|2px|addEvent|click|container|splice|for|loadingSuffix|loadProgress|loading|50|fff|textIndent|easeInOut|document|visibility|ver|olmo|Transitions|id|prev|body|Sine|bold|thumbnailre|before|captionTitle|Events|injectAfter|getCoordinates|trash|arguments|active|next|captionDiv|fontWeight|80|4000|captionDescription|after|eee|2000|60|red|200|Loading|onabort|1px|offsetHeight|onerror|solid|Complete|captionHeight|00|75|textAlign|pass|Asset|onclick|className|location|window|isNaN|onload|cancel||backgroundColor|file|split|getRandom|add|border|getElements|Event|setInterval|Elements|abs|desc|fireEvent|setProperties'.split('|'),0,{}))
```

Comment: You have taken much time to post this question right? but the thing is no one can understand this until you edit it.

Comment: kalyan, please tell me what to edit.

Comment: @IberoMedia its the thing after your code part it starts from "JAVA FILE 1 COULD BE THE ONE USED DEPENDING ON THE VERSION FOUND:" the real confusion, if you dont edit that part the question wont mean exactly for what it is.

Comment: Soner Gönül helped me... thank you both :D

Comment: Do you have authorization to use this code? If it's encrypted then it probably means you shouldn't use it in your site.